# Why are nearly none of my images appearing in a browser all of a sudden?

Tags: html, image, github

My [website](http://glutenfreeradio.co) has been up and running for almost a year now without a hitch. But all of a sudden, my images aren't displaying in any browser. It's strange because no changes had been made to any of the code. I just visited the site one day and noticed the problem. I use [GitHub Pages](https://github.com/stephenshutters/stephenshutters.github.io), which is case sensitive, but all my cases are formatted correctly. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went to your homepage and saw the photo in the background. Your logo appears, also, on some of the sub-pages.
Can you provide a bit more information? Like, what images are missing? Or what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Good point. I apologize for being unclear. The background and menu logo show up, but the large logo on the homepage, photos of artists on the music page, photos of albums on the artists’ pages, photos of artists and albums on the reviews page, et cetera are no longer displaying.

Comment: Hi- so this seems to be a CSS issue. And at the moment your CSS file, http://glutenfreeradio.co/assets/css/site.css, is extremely hard to read. I'd really strongly recommend copying all of your CSS and putting it into a tool like https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/ , which would make it much easier to read and debug. Just re the logo image on your homepage, look for ".collection-type-template-page #title-area" in your CSS and make it so that it's not completely opaque - its opacity is currently 0, make it 1. That will make it visible.

Comment: ...and hopefully a similar approach will work for your other images!

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I wonder why everything worked for a year. Thanks for the advice!